# How to get the sum of triangle in the matrix

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

In my limited experience with numpy。
How to find the sum of triange in the 0/1 square matrix?

```
0 1 0
1 1 1
```

the size of triangle is 2;

```
0 0 1 0 0
0 1 1 1 0
1 1 1 1 1
```

the size of triange is 3;

Matrix:

1     1    1     1     1

0     1    1     1     1

1     1    1     1     1

1     1    1     1     1

the results: [(2,8),(3,2)], I am intering in it and wrote a script, I don't think it's good, so anybody give better answer?

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import numpy as np
import math

a=np.random.randint(0,2,size=[20,20])
print(a)
x_a, y_a = a.shape

def oneTriangle(list):
    tri=np.ones(list,dtype=int)
    tri_upper_no_diag=np.triu(tri,k=1)[::-1]
    tri_lower_no_diag=np.tril(tri,k=0)

    a=np.concatenate((tri_upper_no_diag,tri_lower_no_diag),axis=1)

    b=np.delete(a,0,axis=1)

    return b

def subsearch(a, b):
    number = 0
    x_b, y_b = b.shape

    for i in range(0,a.shape[0]):
        for j in range(0,a.shape[1]):
            #print(i,j)
            c = a[i:(i+x_b), j:(j+y_b)]
            if((c.shape == b.shape) and ((c == b).all())):
                #print(c,'\n', b)
                number = number + 1
    return (number, x_b)

min_value = min(x_a, y_a)
for i in range(2, min_value):
    b = oneTriangle([i, i])
    #print(b)
    number = subsearch(a, b)
    print(number)
```

Comment: A clear problem statement is missing. What exactly makes a triangle. Is upside down triangle a triangle? Is the one turned sideways? Does the base have to be attached to a border of the matrix? Why does the 3rd example have answer `[(2,8),(3,2)]` while the previous ones were a single number?

Comment: only find the upside  triangle not down triangle.